# How to base point selection on a distance in a certain direction in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, selection-tools

My problem is concerning this pipe with blades created with Geometry Nodes. I'd like to move the blades at the ends inwards in direction of the path by the radius of the blades. As you can see right now the center point of the cross-section of the blades at the ends is offset so that half of the blades are just in the air and not connected to the pipe.

[image: screenshot of the problem]

Basically how the whole concept works is that I instance circles on the path, which are instanced again by the blades (curve line).

I've tried around a bit with endpoint selection, but it doesn't work as the input to the node instance on points is the node "curve to points" (in the picture it's called "# Axial Blades"). Endpoint selection can only be used on curves as far as I've experienced so far.

[image: screenshot of geo nodes]

Moving the blades or the circles is not an option because then they are not aligned correctly with the given path, the blades intersect the pipe, etc.
So basically my problem is I'm not able to use endpoint selection and I also don't even know how many points I would need to exclude so that blades aren't moving off the pipe.

I hope you understand my problem and maybe can help me with this.

[image]

Comment: Some variation of instancing on faces, rather than points, might be a way to go?

Comment: Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, resample the curve with the Resample Curve node, set to "Length". Use the blade radius as the length input.

Then in your "Axial Blades"-group right before converting the curve to points, delete the first and last points of the curve with the Delete Geometry node together with the Endpoint Selection node as input, as below:

[image]

This will offset the first and last instance by the radius of the blades.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! So easy actually!